# QTableView screen overflow when large amounts of data are added instead of scrollable TableView

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

I am designing a simple form with two buttons and a TableView with Qt and python using PySide6.

[image: Qt Editor screenshot showing form and DOM tree]

forms.ui

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>CopyToResearch</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="CopyToResearch">
  <property name="windowModality">
   <enum>Qt::NonModal</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>121</width>
    <height>160</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="MinimumExpanding">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Anonymize clinical patients</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget" native="true">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="loadButton">
        <property name="acceptDrops">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="toolTip">
         <string>Load data from file</string>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>&amp;Load from file...</string>
        </property>
        <property name="shortcut">
         <string>Ctrl+L</string>
        </property>
        <property name="flat">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QTableView" name="tableView">
        <property name="locale">
         <locale language="English" country="Netherlands"/>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
         <enum>QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContents</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="alternatingRowColors">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="startButton">
        <property name="toolTip">
         <string>Start copying patients</string>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>&amp;Start</string>
        </property>
        <property name="shortcut">
         <string>Ctrl+S</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

main.py:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QTableView,
)
from PySide6.QtCore import (
    QAbstractTableModel,
    QCoreApplication,
    QFile,
    QModelIndex,
    QPersistentModelIndex,
    QObject,
    Qt,
)
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from typing import Union, Any, Optional

import os
import pandas as pd
import random
import sys


class CopyToResearchModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent: Optional[QObject] = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._data = None

    def get_dataframe(self):
        return self._data

    def set_dataframe(self, dataframe: pd.DataFrame):

        self.beginResetModel()
        self._data = dataframe

        # Add status column as first column
        if not self._data.empty:
            self._data.insert(loc=0, column="Status", value=None)

        self.endResetModel()

    def setData(
        self,
        index: Union[QModelIndex, QPersistentModelIndex],
        value: Any,
        role: int = Qt.EditRole,
    ) -> bool:
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        if (
            not index.isValid()
            or role != Qt.EditRole
            or not (0 <= row <= self.rowCount())
            or not (0 <= column <= self.columnCount())
        ):
            return False
        self._data.iloc[row, column] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True

    def columnCount(
        self,
        parent: Union[QModelIndex, QPersistentModelIndex] = ...,
    ) -> int:
        try:
            return self._data.shape[1]
        except:
            pass

        return 0

    def data(
        self,
        index: Union[QModelIndex, QPersistentModelIndex],
        role: Qt.ItemDataRole = ...,
    ) -> Any:
        if index.isValid() and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])

    def headerData(
        self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int = ...
    ) -> Any:
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[section]

    def rowCount(
        self,
        parent: Union[QModelIndex, QPersistentModelIndex] = ...,
    ) -> int:
        try:
            return self._data.shape[0]
        except:
            pass

        return 0


class CopyToResearch(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        # Load form
        self.load_ui()

        # Find the QTbaleView and set it's model
        self.view = self.findChild(QTableView, name="tableView")
        self.model = CopyToResearchModel(self)
        self.view.setModel(self.model)

        # Make window appear on top of RayStation application window, otherwise it hides behind it
        self.setWindowState(self.windowState() & ~Qt.WindowMinimized | Qt.WindowActive)

        # Add actions to buttons
        load_button = self.findChild(QPushButton, name="loadButton")
        load_button.clicked.connect(self.load_file)

        start_button = self.findChild(QPushButton, name="startButton")
        start_button.clicked.connect(self.copy_patients)

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent), "form.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()

        # Explicitly set window title, apparently the definition in ui file is not honoured
        self.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.tr("Anonymize clinical patients"))

    def load_file(self):
        # Mimic loading from CSV file
        count = 100
        self.model.set_dataframe(
            pd.DataFrame(
                data=[
                    [
                        str(i),
                        str(i),
                        str(i),
                        random.choice([True, False]),
                        random.choice([True, False]),
                        random.choice([True, False]),
                        random.choice([True, False]),
                        random.choice([True, False]),
                    ]
                    for i in range(1, count + 1)
                ],
                columns=[
                    "Clinical Id",
                    "Anonymized Id",
                    "Anonymized Name",
                    "Retain Dates",
                    "Retain Device Identity",
                    "Retain Institution Identity",
                    "Retain UIDs",
                    "Retain Safe Private Attributes",
                ],
            )
        )

        # Force resize to also fit column headers to fit
        self.view.resizeColumnsToContents()

    def copy_patients(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = CopyToResearch()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I keep having issues with part of my window falling off the screen when the TableView contains lots of rows. It also pushes the start button off the screen in such cases.

[image: Part of the content falling off the bottom of the screen, no scroll bars :-(]

When I maximize the window it seems to work OK, bottom of form is against the bottom of the  screen and my TableView has scrollbars so I can drag the rows overflowing into the viewport.

[image: Maximized: Tableview is clipped and has scrollbars, bottom button is visible]

I already tried all kind of options like setting MaximumSize and MaximumHeight, but then I lose the Maximize functionality.
Also played around with a variety of SizePolicy options on the widget itself (and it's parent) but have not find a working set.

How can I make sure:

1. the window is clipped at the edge (this case the bottom) of the screen when layoutChanged() is emitted?
2. the TableView gets as much of the real estate that is available in vertical direction?
3. I still will be able to minimize and maximize the window?

Edit: added minimal example

Comment: The form alone seems fine enough, so the problem might be elsewhere. Are you adding that form to another layout? How are items added? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I will see if I can add a minimal reproducible example, but this is all of the UI.